# setting axes off for all figures using 'set' and 'gca'

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Since I am working on images, I do not want to have axes for all my axes. 
I can do by inserting 'axis off' for every figure. But I was wondering if anyone could propose a method to set the axis off for all figure using 'set' and 'gca'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the list of default properties you can set for your graphics here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161797

You can accomplish what you need by setting

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesVisible','off')
```

before you begin plotting. If you want to do this on a plot-by-plot basis, you can also try

```
set(gca(), 'Visible', 'off')
```